# is it possible to run swift on a webpage like js or swift to interact with JS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I'm not sure how viable this is (from a web performant POV) but I was wondering if Swift code can be run inside of a website?

For example adding to your HTML mark up like a script tag for JS?

Use case:

IOS has a low powermode that prevents some website features (such as `autoplay` video) - while you can use js event listener to detect suspend I have found this unreliable as a metric (as clicking off page causes suspend on video).

I was wondering if swift can be used to quickly detect if lowpower mode is being used and pass/create some flag for JS to detect and alter the design / functions accordingly.

I briefly read through the Swift docs but could use a swift developer weighing in on the possibilities of this workaround.

**IDEALLY** there would be a media query for low power mode like: `@media and (low-power){}` but this does not seem to be a current feature for CSS

Comment: No, you cannot run Swift in a web page.  Swift is a compiled language.

Comment: Swift being a "compiled" language has nothing to do with running it in a browser. Many "compiled" languages have web-asm compilers that let you run compiled code in the browser.

Comment: Fair point. What I meant was, as you stated in your answer, you can't run arbitrary swift code with native access to the device APIs in the browser. It can't do anything that JavaScript can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Swift runs in the browser but it cannot access system APIs unless you run it inside a custom-made browser.

### Running swift in a browser

It is possible to run Swift code in a browser. You can use [SwiftWasm](https://swiftwasm.org) for that. Some practical information can be found in the [SwiftWasm book](https://book.swiftwasm.org/index.html)

### Swift ⇄ JavaScript interaction

It is also possible to interact with JavaScript. See: https://github.com/swiftwasm/JavaScriptKit

### System API Access

It is not possible to access system APIs through a normal browser though. If you want access to those APIs, you should create a native app. Note that from within native apps you can also create web content. In such apps you do have access to system APIs through [`WKUserContentController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller)'s [`add(_:name:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) method.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - just to be clear, what your saying is yes, swift can run in the browser but will not have access to the devices api - so for this use case it is not possible? Thanks again

Comment: Indeed, I updated the answer to clarify this.